Create table in iceberg without using spark
I am facing this issue since many days. I am trying to insert data into iceberg withoug using pyspark. But not getting any solution.
Help me with this
I refered many websites to learn about creating the table in iceberg. But nothing worked for me and I see only pyspark for that

See https://tabular.io/blog/java-api-part-1/

It's not perfect by any means, but this is the closest that you can get right now: https://github.com/apache/iceberg-python
An example with polars+duckdb https://performancede.substack.com/p/iceberg-tables-via-duck-db-and-polars
